# Can't register Android device with Trigger.io and Parse.com: Installation row never created

Tags: android, push-notification, trigger.io

In using trigger.io, I am trying to use Parse in order to send push notifications to both Android and iOS clients. iOS works just fine, but my Nexus 7 doesn't seem to get registered on Parse.com. I.e. when calling `forge.parse.installationInfo` on the client-side, I do get a guid (e.g. 15c8630c-3862-4197-xxx-xxxxxxxx) but in Parse.com, there is no Installation row for Android at all. Even stranger than that, when I restart the app, consecutive calls to installationInfo give a different guid each time, but none of them are making it to parse.com.

What am I missing?

Candide

Answer (score 1):

Never mind... it ended up working... At some point I just started receiving the notifications on my Nexus, I checked on Parse.com and there was the Installation record for my device.

I don't know where this lagging came from; definitely worth keeping an eye on. Anyway, glad the problem's now gone for me.

Comment: What is the solution ? I'm also getting same error :( no registered device found

Comment: Is it going to be late device registration?

Answer (score 0):

For Android : 
Have you ParsePush.subscribeInBackground ?

This is my [solution](http://ubaidiyakob.blogspot.com/2015/03/parse-cant-find-any-registered-devices.html) or just paste codes below into your onCreate

```
    ParsePush.subscribeInBackground("", new SaveCallback() {
        @Override
        public void done(ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {
                Log.d("com.parse.push", "successfully subscribed to the broadcast channel.");
            } else {
                Log.e("com.parse.push", "failed to subscribe for push", e);
            }
        }
    });
```